# iPhoneSDK: UIBarButtonItem's selector method targets wrong instances

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

This Happens only when I open and close the keyboard, is that a problem with "UIResponder"? Or is that about "removefromsubview" ?

I have a custom toolbar and seems like my UIBarButtonItems are targeting the wrong instance of QuestionTableViewController, so it triggers a selector method of a previosly loaded controller in the stack but not the selector method of the current object.

First page shows correct but when second time I load this nib to navigation controller then it targets the first object's action method not the current object.

**In my RootViewController I load eachtime this nibs for different pages:**

```
QuestionTableViewController *questionViewController = [[QuestionTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuestionTableViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Then in the viewDidload method of QuestionTableViewController I do this;

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:nextArrow style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(localNextView:)] autorelease];
        rightButton.width=120.0f;                       
self.customToolBar= [[[CustomToolbar alloc] 
                                       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,436,self.navigationController.view.frame.size.width, 44)] autorelease];
[self.customToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:bckButton, rightButton, nil] animated:NO];                      
        [self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.customToolBar];

-(void) localNextView:(id)sender {
//i.e when i am on the third page, here when i check the 
//sender I see the object belongs to first page!!
}
```

And then I remove it on viewWillDisappear, I remove it from navigationcontroller to be sure that the next view uses its own toolbar but not a previois instance;

```
[self.customToolBar removeFromSuperview];
self.customToolBar=nil;
```

Comment: have you implement  the localNextView method? if yes then put the code here..?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the same uibarbutton and selector target for each time the view is shown. You should change the content of the triggered method though. You can do that in the ViewWillAppear because the ViewDidLoad is only called once.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
// do de stuff for this view-show here.
// could be something like this. 
// viewcounter is a property and 
// an integer set to 0 in the ViewDidLoad
// and updated with viewcounter = counterview+1 each time you go to next page
switch (viewcounter){
   case 1: { do A ; break;}
   case 2: { do B ; break;}
 }
}
```

The thing you could do is change text of labels, set values or titles to buttons etc etc. Of course these items has to be outlets

Comment: tnx but this does not answer my question, and also how do i change content of triggered method in viewwillappear?

Comment: this does not help me, i want to find the bug in my current system

Comment: I think it is the wrong approach (although maybe not impossible). You should change the content of your "infrastructure" and not the infrastructure itself. Secondly ViewDidLoad is really loaded only once. So that is why your code is not working.

Comment: viewDidLoad is called only when I load a nib file isn't it? Here every new page is loaded as a new nib file and pushed to navigation stack so it should be called.